# Using ADODB to print recordset to an Excel sheet

Tags: vba, ado

I'm trying to use an ADODB connection to create a record set from a query, then copy the contents of that record set into a range of cells

Below is the outline of my code, but I keep getting errors

> Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)' Unspecified error

(I've replaced my specific references with all caps dummy references)

```
Sub Subroutine()

'establish ADODB connection to retrieve data from TABLE

Dim objConnection As New ADODB.connection
Dim objRecordset As New ADODB.Recordset

With objConnection
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source = MYDATASOURCE" & _
    "Extended Properties = Excel 8.0;HDR = Yes;"
    .Open
End With

'use query to record data to Excel range
Set objRecordset = objConnection.OpenRecordset("Select * From TABLE Where FieldNm = NAME")

With objRecordset
.Open
.MoveFirst

Do Until .EOF
    Worksheets("WORKSHEET").Cells(14, 1) = objRecordset.Fields.Item("FieldNm")
    .MoveNext
Loop

End With

End Sub
```

The debug goes to the `.Open` in my `With objConnection` block.  Before that I was having problems with the `.MoveNext` method.

Comment: Did you tried `Worksheets("WORKSHEET").Range("A14").CopyFromRecordset objRecordset`?

Comment: I usually do it like this: `objRecordset.Open sSelectStatement, objConnection`

Comment: What is sSelectStatement?

Comment: Please provide actual query as this is not compatible with Excel workbooks: `Select * From TABLE Where FieldNm = NAME`. Also, wrap your sub in error handling to get specific message.

Comment: @Parfait my data is in an Excel table in another location, so TABLE is the name of my range.  What exactly about my query is not compatible with Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your SQL is correctly specifying worksheet range, consider adjusting some items in and outside of `With...End With` block.

- [OpenRecordset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820966.aspx) is a DAO method. Use [Recordset.Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/open-method-ado-recordset) for ADO
- Remove the second `.Open` call
- Remove the recordset name inside `With`
- Loop through worksheet down the rows instead of reassign same cell
- Use error handling for more informative error message to capture runtime exceptions

VBA

```
Sub Subroutine()
On Error Goto ErrHandle

    '...same as above...

    objRecordset.Open "Select * From TABLE Where FieldNm = NAME", objConnection

    With objRecordset
        .MoveLast
        .MoveFirst

        i = 0
        Do Until .EOF
            Worksheets("WORKSHEET").Cells(14 + i, 1) = .Fields("FieldNm")

            i = i + 1
            .MoveNext
        Loop    

        .Close
    End With

    objConnection.Close

ExitHandle:
    Set objRecordset = Nothing
    Set objConnection = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    Msgbox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "RUNTIME ERROR"
    Resume ExitHandle
End Sub
```

Comment: If `FieldNm` is a non-numeric field, you may also need to use apostrophes around the value, i.e. `Select * From TABLE Where FieldNm = 'NAME'`.

Comment: Indeed. OP seems to suggest query is OK and SQL is likely pseudo code placeholder.

Comment: It makes it really hard to help them when they do that.  It's so much easier if they obfuscate their data by just changing alphanumeric characters to other alphanumeric characters, and numbers to other numbers, and leave all special characters untouched.

Comment: Thanks YowE3K, that's a good idea.  I'll do that next time to try and preserve the types