# Excel VBA running Access query may return multiple records

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I'm running the following query in a macro (with Excel VBA) to an Access database.  It works good when only 1 record is returned.  I've been made aware that multiple records could be returned.

I'm stuck on trying to identify when there are multiple records so I can add each additional record to the worksheet.  Once I know there are multiple records, I'll write the 1st record and then increment the row number (x) by 1 to write the 2nd, 3rd, etc.

I haven't had this situation before so I'm not sure how (1) to identify if there are multiple records and (2) how to write the 2nd record.  Is the first field in the 2nd record going to be Recordset.Fields(11)?

Thanks for the help..........

```
Dim Recordset As ADODB.Recordset
Set Recordset = New ADODB.Recordset

vDataBase = "Y:\Groups\Corporate Accounting\AutoMonarch\ Translate\Titles.mdb"
ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= '" & vDataBase & "';Persist Security Info=False"

vSql = ""
vSql = "Select bo_id, buyers_order_date, mileage, contact_name, contact_phone, cust_legal_name, address, city, state, zip, country, location_phone from buyerinfo where unit = '" & vArrUnit(q) & "'"

Call Recordset.Open(vSql, ConnectionString, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, CommandTypeEnum.adCmdText)

If Recordset.BOF And Recordset.EOF Then
'      do something to indicate no records returned
Else

   Cells(x, 4) = Recordset.Fields(1).Value
   Cells(x, 5) = Recordset.Fields(2).Value
   ....
   Cells(x, 12) = Recordset.Fields(10).Value

End If
```

Comment: Aren't there questions (that have been answered) about looping through a recordset on this site?

Comment: Look into `MoveNext` method or `GetRows` method of `ADODB.RecordSet`. You can check the amount of returned records with `RecordsCount` property. [Here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518422/using-adodb-to-print-recordset-to-an-excel-sheet)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ADODB to print recordset to an Excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518422/using-adodb-to-print-recordset-to-an-excel-sheet)

Comment: @VictorK  - Does a reliable use of a records count property rely on a static records retrieval?

Comment: To use `RecordCount`, you must use `CursorLocation = adUseClient`

Comment: @Jeeped I would assume so. In some places I've seen chained `RS.MoveLast` & `RS.MoveFirst` which I assume is supposed to rectify that. Can't speak to efficiency of that method.

Comment: @VictorK..........I just tried RecordsCount  but I got -1 for every result.  4 lines returned 1 record and 1 line returned 0 records.  I must be doing something wrong.........I used tmpnum = recordset.recordcount

Comment: @JohnyL...........Do you have an example that I could see?  Thanks....

Comment: @JohnyL...........Please disregard.  I found an example and it RecordCount is working exactly like I had hoped that it would.  Now I have to work on writing the multiple records.  Thanks again

Comment: @Shaves If you find an answer elsewhere on SO you may consider deleting your question.

Comment: You can loop through the records in the recordset using a simple for loop, however through years of working with recordsets etc the best move is to dump your data in an array and then use the array for whatever you want: `arr=recordset.getrows()`

Comment: @VictorK You need both `rs.MoveLast` and `rs.MoveFirst` and `CursorLocation = adUseClient`. If you don't have the first one, the entire recordset might not yet be loaded when you determine the count, if you don't use the last one you have an invalid cursor so it will throw an error on count.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but this sound like a weird setup.  Can you run a 'Find Duplicates Query Wizard'?  Maybe you can do a Countif in Excel, if that's your ask.

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1499-count-duplicate-values-in-column.html